# Cant place views at the bottom of the screen in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to take that Signup button at the bottom of the screen but it does not allow me to place any view at the bottom of the black line which is shown in picture  Can anybody tell me why ?

[image: Layout Picture]

**userSignin.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    />
    <RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="SignUp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_signup"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Username :"
        android:id="@+id/tv_username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_signup"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CB_bbq"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CB_bbq" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SignUp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CB_chinese" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chinese"
        android:id="@+id/CB_chinese"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bbq"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_signup" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FastFood"
        android:id="@+id/CB_fastfood"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_chinese"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:checked="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BBQ"
        android:id="@+id/CB_bbq"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_chinese"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_username" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pizza"
        android:id="@+id/CB_pizza"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CB_fastfood"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_fastfood"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_bbq" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Select KM at which you notify for any ALert"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_chinese"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Select interested time"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Breakfast"
        android:id="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_chinese" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Brunch"
        android:id="@+id/CB_brunch"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_fastfood" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lunch"
        android:id="@+id/CB_lunch"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:checked="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi Tea"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dinner"
        android:id="@+id/CB_dinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_lunch"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_lunch"
        android:checked="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Midnight Deals"
        android:id="@+id/CB_md"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Select Food Type"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CB_pizza" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/id_km"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/CB_dinner"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CB_dinner"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CB_md" />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: fillViewPost= "true"

Comment: set android:fillViewport="true" for scrollview

Comment: @android Please have a look on my answer. hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scrollview you need to make `android:fillViewport="true"` instead of false reason as ScrollView wrap the content and leave the available area as unused if you not mark fillViewPort="true".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    />
    <RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="SignUp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_signup"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Username :"
        android:id="@+id/tv_username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_signup"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CB_bbq"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CB_bbq" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SignUp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CB_chinese" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chinese"
        android:id="@+id/CB_chinese"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bbq"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_signup" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FastFood"
        android:id="@+id/CB_fastfood"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_chinese"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:checked="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BBQ"
        android:id="@+id/CB_bbq"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_chinese"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_username" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pizza"
        android:id="@+id/CB_pizza"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CB_fastfood"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_fastfood"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_bbq" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Select KM at which you notify for any ALert"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_chinese"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Select interested time"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Breakfast"
        android:id="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_chinese" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Brunch"
        android:id="@+id/CB_brunch"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_fastfood" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lunch"
        android:id="@+id/CB_lunch"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:checked="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi Tea"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bf"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dinner"
        android:id="@+id/CB_dinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CB_lunch"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_lunch"
        android:checked="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Midnight Deals"
        android:id="@+id/CB_md"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Select Food Type"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CB_pizza" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/id_km"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/CB_dinner"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CB_dinner"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CB_md" />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="SignUp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_signup"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter Username :"
            android:id="@+id/tv_username"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_signup"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/et_username"
            android:layout_above="@+id/CB_bbq"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CB_bbq" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SignUp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CB_chinese" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chinese"
            android:id="@+id/CB_chinese"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bbq"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_signup" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FastFood"
            android:id="@+id/CB_fastfood"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_chinese"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:checked="false" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BBQ"
            android:id="@+id/CB_bbq"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_chinese"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_username" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pizza"
            android:id="@+id/CB_pizza"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CB_fastfood"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_fastfood"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_bbq" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Select KM at which you notify for any ALert"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_chinese"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Select interested time"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Breakfast"
            android:id="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_chinese" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Brunch"
            android:id="@+id/CB_brunch"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_fastfood" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lunch"
            android:id="@+id/CB_lunch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:checked="false" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi Tea"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dinner"
            android:id="@+id/CB_dinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_lunch"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_lunch"
            android:checked="false" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Midnight Deals"
            android:id="@+id/CB_md"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:checked="false" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Select Food Type"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/CB_pizza" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id_km"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/CB_dinner"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CB_dinner"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CB_md" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing line `android:fillViewport="true"`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `layout_gravity="center"`

Remove this line for signup button

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Replace this button

```
 <Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SignUp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CB_chinese" />
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

put android:fillViewport="true" and make the RelativeLayout the parent of the scrollView

Answer (score 0):

Put button outside the scrollview.

Comment: scrollview is the parent there, how can he keep that outside scrollview -_- and small things like these should be mentioned in comments

Comment: Use another parent layout as  for example Linear Layout and put scrollview in that after that put button

Comment: No its not like that , i have to change only android:fillViewport="false" to "true"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="false">
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="SignUp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_signup"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter Username :"
            android:id="@+id/tv_username"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_signup"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/et_username"
            android:layout_above="@+id/CB_bbq"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CB_bbq" />



        <CheckBox
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chinese"
            android:id="@+id/CB_chinese"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bbq"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_signup" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FastFood"
            android:id="@+id/CB_fastfood"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_chinese"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:checked="false" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BBQ"
            android:id="@+id/CB_bbq"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_chinese"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_username" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pizza"
            android:id="@+id/CB_pizza"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CB_fastfood"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_fastfood"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_bbq" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Select KM at which you notify for any ALert"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_chinese"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Select interested time"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Breakfast"
            android:id="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_chinese" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Brunch"
            android:id="@+id/CB_brunch"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_fastfood" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lunch"
            android:id="@+id/CB_lunch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:checked="false" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi Tea"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_bf"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dinner"
            android:id="@+id/CB_dinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CB_lunch"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CB_lunch"
            android:checked="false" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Midnight Deals"
            android:id="@+id/CB_md"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:checked="false" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Select Food Type"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/CB_pizza" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id_km"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/CB_dinner"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CB_dinner"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CB_md" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        >
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SignUp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CB_chinese" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```